# python spotify api getting access token and refresh token giving 400

Tags: python, oauth-2.0

```
code = "AQB40N8OxnZAjvDcS8Yq6KhL0RqvKPKLCBnwtqHTnXQhMvwSyUgNUJlqyhww6qXoXYYlLZ7MmRP8Eu1XEeG9D2m3wEEdCJVyRos6brJiILl1ynKv-EL5G5dQ3vH418h-G948THH13ndUrrM-q0CDuYA06-aEpGlTk3vxK-g3bNBtS7jYSc82ToDsFgNAjL4WLPGs03Xm1j5I0zDZ7XUJASeqoCchy3-8"



import requests
import json
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic YTU5MWE4OTQ3ZGM4NDIzNDg2NzVlY2Y4MTk3N2M3MmI6YmRiZGJmNmY4Yjg5NDdlNGJhYzM5MzUxMTNmNmVlOGI=',
}

data = {
  'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
  'code': "AQB40N8OxnZAjvDcS8Yq6KhL0RqvKPKLCBnwtqHTnXQhMvwSyUgNUJlqyhww6qXoXYYlLZ7MmRP8Eu1XEeG9D2m3wEEdCJVyRos6brJiILl1ynKv-EL5G5dQ3vH418h-G948THH13ndUrrM-q0CDuYA06-aEpGlTk3vxK-g3bNBtS7jYSc82ToDsFgNAjL4WLPGs03Xm1j5I0zDZ7XUJASeqoCchy3-8",
  'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:8888'
}

response = requests.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', headers=headers, data=data)
print(response)
```

i dont understand why it doesnt work? what's wrong with it exactly? i followed https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because redirect_uri is not encoded.

try this way...

```
data = {

    ...

    'redirect_uri' : 'http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888'
}
```

Comment: could it be because its localhost and not an actual website it doesn't let it happen?